# iOS 8 ABPeoplePickerNavigationController Multiple Selection

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8

I recently upgraded my iPhone and Xcode from iOS 6 to iOS 8 and I experienced the issue of the "default" action being performed when a phone number or email address is selected from the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` (by "default" action I mean, selecting a phone number starts calling that number and selecting an email address opens up a new email to that address).

I implemented the new

**peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson:property:identifier**:

method of `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate`, which resolved the "default" action issue, but now I am unable to select more than one email address or phone number before the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` is dismissed, whereas I used to be able to pick any number of email addresses and phone numbers in iOS 6 by returning NO from the

**peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:**

method which no longer seems to get called. I have also tried setting the `predicateForSelectionOfProperty` property of the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` to nil,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithValue: YES]
```

and

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithValue: NO],
```

but the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` still dismisses as soon as a property is selected.

Any idea how to prevent the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` from dismissing when a property is selected?

Thanks,

Vatche

Comment: picker.predicateForSelectionOfProperty = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:NO]; worked for me :-)

Comment: Setting picker.predicateForSelectionOfProperty = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue: NO] does prevent the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController from dismissing after a property is selected, but the selection of a property no longer triggers the `peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson:property:identifier:` method, so I am not able to capture the property that was selected. How are you capturing the selected property?

Comment: I ended up sublcassing "ABPeoplePickerNavigationController" and overriding "dismissViewControllerAnimated" so that I can decide whether to dismiss or not. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I'll put it as the answer, @vatche please mark it as the correct answer if you feel like.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the comment as an answer since it proved to be helpful :-)

I ended up subclassing `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and overriding `dismissViewControllerAnimated` to be able to decide whether to dismiss it or not, when a property is selected.

Comment: Have you got more details on how to do this? I'm trying to get check marks to work, but ran into the same issue of the delegate not running.

Comment: Not sure what's that you don't understand @Carlos , hope this helps:

**CustomABPeoplePickerNavigationController.h**
`#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@interface CustomABPeoplePickerNavigationController : ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldDismiss;

@end`

**CustomABPeoplePickerNavigationController.m**

`-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    if(self.shouldDismiss){
        [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
    }
}`

Comment: I had a look into it. I think in the new version some of this is deprecated. Also someone suggested the delegates won't run unless they're set in the init function. I'll continue to mess with it, thanks.